# VSTS - I want to use an existing deployment definition for a new build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have just completed a build in VSTS.
Now I want to deploy it.
I am doing this manually whilst I learn how to do this.
I have a previous deployment definition that worked for a previous build.
But when I click on Release for my latest build, that definition is not available.
I get this message instead;

```
There are no release definitions associated with this build definition. Do you wish to create a new one?
```

So how do I associate a previous release definition with a new build?

Comment: Are you talking about two different build **definitions**, or two different builds that were run for the same build definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link an existing release definition to a new build definition, you should remove the old artifact source linking in your release definition. Detail steps as below:

In release definition -> **Artifacts** Tab -> remove current artifacts -> Link an artifact source -> select your new build definition for **Source (Build definition)** and the **Default version** as Latest -> Link -> save -> create release.

[image][image]

Then your new build will be deployed by the existing release definition.

**Note:** If you don't have permission to edit release definition and if you have permission to create release definition, you can **clone** the current release and modify and Artifacts as you need.
[image]

Comment: I find the options to Edit and Remove are disabled. Presumably I do not have the correct permissions, which ones should I ask for?

Comment: This is mainly you have not permission to edit release definition. You can ask the administrator to allow you to edit release definition. And if you have permission to create release definition, you can use the way I added In the end of my answer.